# Polymorphism in Create Package (MariaDB 10.6.4)

Tags: package, mariadb, polymorphism, mariadb-10.6

is it possible (or maybe will it be?) to use **polymorphism** in `CREATE PACKAGE` and `CREATE PACKAGE BODY` statements in MariaDB?

This is due to a migration of some package from Oracle to MariaDB. I have to recode some parts but I cannot change names (i.e. I should change every call to the new-named procedures in the rest of the software to migrate).

Example (set @@sql_mode already called):

```
create package P as
    procedure X (par1 INT)
    procedure X (par2 VARCHAR, par3 INT)
    function F (par1 INT) return INT
    function F (par2 VARCHAR) return VARCHAR
end;
```

At the moment, of course, the statement execution fails with error:

```
ERROR 1304 (42000) at line 3 in file: 'filename.sql': PROCEDURE P.X already exists
```

Thank you all.

```
Configuration: Oracle Virtualbox - Mariadb 10.6.4, Xubuntu 20.4.3 LTS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW CREATE PACKAGE BODY employee_tools\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Package body: employee_tools
            sql_mode: PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,IGNORE_SPACE,ORACLE,NO_KEY_OPTIONS,NO_TABLE_OPTIONS,NO_FIELD_OPTIONS,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
 Create Package Body: CREATE DEFINER="root"@"localhost" PACKAGE BODY "employee_tools" AS
  
  stdRaiseAmount DECIMAL(10,2):=500;
  
  PROCEDURE log (eid INT, ecmnt TEXT) AS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO employee_log (id, cmnt) VALUES (eid, ecmnt);
  END;
  
  PROCEDURE hire(ename TEXT, esalary DECIMAL(10,2)) AS
    eid INT;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO employee (name, salary) VALUES (ename, esalary);
    eid:= last_insert_id();
    log(eid, 'hire ' || ename);
  END;

  FUNCTION getSalary(eid INT) RETURN DECIMAL(10,2) AS
    nSalary DECIMAL(10,2);
  BEGIN
    SELECT salary INTO nSalary FROM employee WHERE id=eid;
    log(eid, 'getSalary id=' || eid || ' salary=' || nSalary);
    RETURN nSalary;
  END;

  PROCEDURE raiseSalary(eid INT, amount DECIMAL(10,2)) AS
  BEGIN
    UPDATE employee SET salary=salary+amount WHERE id=eid;
    log(eid, 'raiseSalary id=' || eid || ' amount=' || amount);
  END;

  PROCEDURE raiseSalaryStd(eid INT) AS
  BEGIN
    raiseSalary(eid, stdRaiseAmount);
    log(eid, 'raiseSalaryStd id=' || eid);
  END;

BEGIN  
  log(0, 'Session ' || connection_id() || ' ' || current_user || ' started');
END
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
  Database Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).